# Adding entry to task_struct and initializing to default value

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I want to add an entry to process control block structure (`task_struct`). Let say a way to tag some process.  I want to initialize this field to 0 for all the process except "some special processes", later by calling `sched_setscheduler()` I will set this flag for the "special processes".

Does anybody have an idea how to assign a default value to a member variable in `task_struct`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about a recent Linux kernel, because implementation detail changes over time.

There are two options. The first - you can set the value of the variable in the `init_task` global. See how it is done in the `linux/init_task.h` header. The second option is to add code to `copy_process`, which you might want to do anyway in order to properly handle the `fork()` inheritance of the field you are adding.